# Execute statement by shortcut in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I execute any statement in MySQLWorkbench using shortcut? Now I have to press button (yellow lightning). Of course I have read this in the documentation: [Table 14.6 - query menu](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html#wb-shortcuts-query-menu) (Table 14.6 - query menu) but I don't know what does mean `Modifier+Return` ?

As we can read `Modifier` is `Ctrl` (in Windows) but what is `Return`?

Comment: List of keys: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`Return` = `Enter` key. So `Ctrl + Enter` key should execute.

Answer (score 68):

### MySQL Workbench 6.3

---

#### Default key mapping

- Execute (All or Selection) -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Execute Current Statement -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

  [image: Query > Execute]

---

#### Change the default mapping

Open:

**C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\data\main_menu.xml**

If you search for *Execute (All or Selection)* and for *Execute Current Statement*, you'll also identify (based on what you see in the screenshot above) the meaning of ***Modifier*** and ***Return***:

- Modifier = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- Return = <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Here you can change the default mappings.
Being familiar with other tools like SQuirreL SQL and pgAdmin, I always prefer to run only the selected query using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>, so I change the following in the main_menu.xml:

1. To run the selected query using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```xml
    <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.query.exec"> 
      <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.query</link> 
      <value type="string" key="caption">Execute (All or Selection)</value> 
      <value type="string" key="name">query.execute</value> 
      <value type="string" key="command">builtin:query.execute</value> 
      <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value> 
      <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+Return</value>
    </value> 
    ...
    <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.query.execute_current_statementwin"> 
      <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.query</link> 
      <value type="string" key="caption">Execute Current Statement</value> 
      <value type="string" key="name">query.execute_current_statement</value> 
      <value type="string" key="command">builtin:query.execute_current_statement</value> 
      <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value> 
      <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+Shift+Return</value>
      <value type="string" key="platform">windows</value>
    </value>
```

2. Run the selected query using <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```xml
    <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.query.exec"> 
      <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.query</link> 
      <value type="string" key="caption">Execute (All or Selection)</value> 
      <value type="string" key="name">query.execute</value> 
      <value type="string" key="command">builtin:query.execute</value> 
      <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value> 
      <value type="string" key="shortcut">F5</value>
    </value>
```

Save the file and restart MySQL Workbench to see the changes.

Comment: Hooray for F5 execution! Thanks!

Comment: You can change default mapping in mac  open: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/main_menu.xml

Comment: love the screen shot clearly showing the short cut keys, and how to change them.

Comment: Thanks for that :) On Ubuntu, the path is `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/main_menu.xml`

Comment: using workbench 8.0.19, modified accordingly, `<!--value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+Return</value-->
     <value type="string" key="shortcut">F5</value>
                    <value type="string" key="platform">windows</value>
                </value>`, and `F5` is shown in the `Query` menu. However it executes **ALL** statements not jut the highlighted.

Answer (score 33):

**Executing statement at cursor**

Ctrl + Enter (for Windows)

**Executing all statements within selection**

Ctrl + Shift + Enter Key (for Windows)

[**see here for more**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl + Enter` to execute
you can find full list of shortcodes on following link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

For Mac:
`Command + Return` should work.

PS. this executes whatever you have in the query editor until it finds `';'`.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, the shortcut is

```
Command + Enter
```

You can find all keyboard shortcuts from [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to customize** the selection so that both will run with a shortcut

1.) the partial selection or run selected to curser, then you need to update:

the shortcut element in the node com.mysql.wb.menu.query.exec in the main_menu.xml file.

how I have mine set:

```
<value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.query.exec">
    <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.query</link>
    <value type="string" key="accessibilityName">Execute All or Selection</value>
    <value type="string" key="caption">Execute (All or Selection)</value>
    <value type="string" key="name">query.execute</value>
    <value type="string" key="command">builtin:query.execute</value>
    <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>
    <value type="string" key="shortcut">F6</value>
</value>
```

2.) for updating the execute the entire page (regardless or what is selected), then change:

the element shortcut in either:
com.mysql.wb.menu.query.execute_current_statementwin (windows)
com.mysql.wb.menu.query.execute_current_statement (non-windows)

how I have mine:

```
<value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.query.execute_current_statementwin">
    <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.query</link>
    <value type="string" key="accessibilityName">Execute Current Statement</value>
    <value type="string" key="caption">Execute Current Statement</value>
    <value type="string" key="name">query.execute_current_statement</value>
    <value type="string" key="command">builtin:query.execute_current_statement</value>
    <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>
    <value type="string" key="shortcut">F5</value>
    <value type="string" key="platform">windows</value>
</value>
```

..unfortunately I was not able to configure this so that F5 would work for both a partial selection and the entire page, so I chose to set one of them to F6. Hope this helps someone out )