# Change shortcut command in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I regularly switch between MacOS and Windows, and use Workbench on both, but Sequel Pro on my Mac also.

I find myself hitting `cmd+R` in Workbench on the Mac quite regularly.

I've done my homework so far and managed to disable the command by commenting out the relevant shortcut in the `main_menu.xml` file from this link.

[Execute statement by shortcut in mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607448/execute-statement-by-shortcut-in-mysql-workbench)

I was wondering if there was any way that I can get the combo to execute the SQL the same way that `cmd+ENTER` does, but also keep `cmd+ENTER`?

Eg, have two shortcuts that run the same command.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to assign more than one shortcut to a command, however you could duplicate the execute command (say, "Run Query 1" and "Run Query 2") with the two shortcuts you want, but the same command to execute. This will produce also 2 menu entries, but that's the lesser evil I believe.